# which one is better performance wise: checking if a==b or a!=b

Tags: performance, scientific-computing

I know that this might seem silly question, that maybe answered like come on just use any it is only n [Yocto-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto-)seconds difference, but I am really curious to know the difference if it exists!

So :

which one is better performance wise: checking if a==b or a!=b

:)

Comment: Regularly it's done that way that `!=` just returns an opposite value of `==`, but everything depends on particular realization in language your're using

Comment: Would really depend on the language compiler and the underlying processor.  If processor has both a BEQ (branch-if-equal) and BNE (branch-not-equal) instruction, then it's just a single instruction.  If not, then depends on how compiler generates machine code.

Comment: If your scientific code depends on the speed of the comparisons, then you are very welcome to come to optimize ours :)

Comment: From my point of view this depends on what your results should be. That means what do you want to with the results --> is there an "if" - clause where, if you check wright, you don´t need an else - clause?!?

Comment: speaking for java the micro optimization performance is taken care by the compiler, however there are few languages like 'DOCUControl' the one that I use clearly states never to use == operator

Comment: thanks guys it is just a question out of curiosity :D

Comment: @Synaps & DBug & Marcel let's say in Java which is better ?

Comment: @Chiel I am not doing anything important but I would be more than happy to optimize your code :D

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't really know how to measure this difference, that why I am here asking

Comment: It depends a lot on what a and b are. If they are numeric values small enough to fit in the register of the machine, there really should not be a difference--pretty much any assembly language does a compare, then allows branching on equal or not equal. If a and b are longer than the register size, perhaps something horrendous like a string or an extended precision number, then != is faster on average, since it allows bailing out as soon as an inequality in any word is found, while the equality test requires checking the entire length of the values.